# After Effects Duplicate Layer Expression

Tags: expression, after-effects

Can you duplicate a layer with an expression. I have a picture that I want to duplicate many times, it's one dollar. I would have to repeat it over 100 times. I have two of these codes, they work. Is it possible to write an expression so that the photo is automatically copied when playing the video, every certain number of frames or seconds?

Position(expression)

```
seedRandom(index, timeless = true); [random(0, 1920), random(0, 1080)];
```

Rotate(expression)

```
seedRandom(index,true); random(70. -70);
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

No, expressions cannot duplicate layers. they can only transform these properties, i.e. position, for example. To duplicate, you need a script.

For example [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Eam05YjWXL7aBNhT3z9juYDRwxU7j9wf/view?usp=sharing).
Create a folder in the Project window and put in it what you want to duplicate. then select that folder and run the script. the parameters are easy to understand. as a result, you will create a composition with duplicates of what you put in that folder.